# can I use random.choices reverse?

Tags: python

I know random.choices order have a probability function. But it only uses when I got higher probability, higher choice chance. But I need a reverse function. It means if I got a higher probability, a lower choice chance. (Maybe it is equal to lower probability, higher choice chance)
Can I use like that?
Please give me help..

Comment: Maybe give an example of what you mean. I am not sure I understand.

Comment: what is your priority? Do you want to find an element from a list with least probability of occurrence or you want to use the choice() function only to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) to reverse your weights.

For example if we had an incredibly biased coin with only a ten percent chance of landing on tails:

```
>>> import random
>>> coins = "H", "T"
>>> flips = 0.9, 0.1
>>> count = 1_000_000  # one million iterations
>>> len([c for c in random.choices(coins, weights=flips, k=count) if c == 'T']) / count
0.099978
>>> len([c for c in random.choices(coins, weights=reversed(flips), k=count) if c == 'T']) / count
0.899772
```